# (Discord.js) Delete channels with specified text in name of Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically as the title says. I'm wondering if there's a way of deleting all channels that contain a specific string for their name

E.g. 18876557 **-old**

On command, delete all channels that names contain the string **-old**.

Comment: Loop through the channels and check their names, I'll write you an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Channel.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete)

```js
// iterate a function through all channels in the guild
guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
  if (guild.name.includes('-old')) // if the string '-old' is found within the channel name
    channel.delete() // delete the channel
      .then(() => console.log(`Deleted ${channel.name}`))
      .catch((e) => console.log(`Could not delete ${channel.name} because of ${e}`)) // handle any errors
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Discord is not defined, I have "const guild = new Discord.Guild();"

Comment: `guild` should be whatever guild you want to do this on. You cannot create a new guild. If this is in a command, you could use `message.guild`. Otherwise: `client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy, you just need to loop through the guild channels:

```
for (let channel of guild.channels.cache) {
    if (channel.name.includes("-old")) channel.delete();
}
```